# How to update widget ID and Versiosn for config.xml based on environment (prod/qa)?

Tags: angular, cordova, config

I am working with Cordova Angular Application. My project maintains different widget id for prod and qa.I don't want to update everytime the version number and id manually while deploying the application. So is there any way to update my Widget Id and Version number automatically by just hitting some command based on the env prod or qa.
[image]

e.g: for prod env:

```
<widget id="ïo.cordova.prod_app" version="1.0.0">
```

e.g: for qa env: `<widget id="ïo.cordova.qa_app" version="1.1.1">`